# get_post_meta is returning image id

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I'm using this script to get image filename, stored in a custom meta called background:

```
$background = get_post_meta( '22', 'background', true );
echo $background;
```

But it is returning the id of the image, not his filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background` is not a Core meta field. Since you say that `get_post_meta( '22', 'background', true );` returns an image ID, I can only assume that whatever saved that value saved the image ID and not the  filename.

You can convert the filename to an URL with [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) or get other information including a partial file name with [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)